# Fail to add Holoeverywhere to Android Studio Library, Error: "hostname in certificate didn't match"

Tags: android-studio, android-holo-everywhere

I followed the guideline in the [github](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/wiki/Import-in-IDE) to add Holoeverywhere in Android Studio (Guidelines as follow).

Guidelines

1. Checkout from Version Control - Git
2. Typo in Repository URL: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere.git
3. Press 'Clone', wait until repository checkout
4. If you use Android Studio, then just click 'Yes' on the proposal to open a project. Otherwise in IDEA press Import project and specify path to downloaded repo, choose gradle model and press next.

Everything went fine from Step 1 - 3. Yet for Step 4, after it asks me to open the project and I clicks "yes", an error pops up: "hostname in certificate didn't match" I retried again, yet in vein.

I also searched in google, yet the materials I found does not help.

What should I do? I was stuck....

Thx in advance for any help

Comment: This is a network problem.

Comment: So you mean it is my network's problem? But I could get on the internet, so what is the problem with that then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, the server is down: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues/855

Any way, if you are starting a project, please, don't use HoloEverywhere. Use minsdk 14. Or, even better, use Material!